# ListView programatically added columns shows type of item

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datagridview, jscript.net

I got a ListView in another assembly and want to add a column to it. The items in the listview are objects of a class in that assembly.

When I add a column like this

```
var col : GridViewColumn = new GridViewColumn();
col.Header = "Header text";
list.View.Columns.Add(col);
```

the column appears but all rows in the listview have the name of the type of the item in that new column. Even when I change the value of the new column (`itemclass.Items[newColIdx] = "zz"`) this does not display. There is no data binding or cell templates involved.

Why is that?

**Edit**: Maybe I can enhance the question: If a ListView.Items contains an array of class A - how do you control which things of A are displayed how in the GridView? I am in the need of reverse engineering here and DisplayMemberBinding is null so it does not use data binding AFAIK.

**Bounty Question**: When `ToString()` is called on every item (which represents a row), how is that mapped towards the columns of the GridView? How must I alter an item in the row so that the new column is filled?

Special problem when trying to find this solution is that this runs in a JScript sandbox within a bigger C# .NET application and no debugging possibility is supplied other than using message boxes and reflection.

**Edit**: The problem is that I am writing a JScript which runs in a 3rd party .NET application and gives me the opportunity to do many things possible with .NET. This is a script adding features to a listview. I can access the listview and it is filled with database data by the 3rd party app. I do not know how it does that. I can programatically add custom rows with custom content (not DB related). But when I add a custom column I do not seem to be able to se its value in den rows.

The added rows are of a type `3rdParty.ListRow` and contain a property `Items` to which I assign a string array. The values of the array are displayed in the representative columns - but not in the added columns. There I only get the text `3rdParty.ListRow` which is because `ToString()` was called on the ListRow.

So: How can I tell the new columns (e.g. index 5) to display `ListRow.Items[5]` and not `ListRow.ToString()`? I liked to do it the same way the already existing columns do it seems that all the properties Alex mentioned are undefined there. How would I set `DataMemberBinding` to achieve mapping to `ListRow.Items[5]`?

Comment: Seems like although your bounty question is answered you wouldn't give up the bounty. Just not fair.

Comment: Just have been out of the country. Awarded the bounnty. I appreciate yourefforts to hel.

Comment: @Alex - I understand the mechanism now and in my last comment I askes for an example: "How would I do it so that it binds to ListRow.Items[5] instead of ListRow.ToString() (as happening now)?" So what will I assign to DisplayMemberBinding if you have any clue. I see to not be able to get it from the existing columns. If you dont know I will leave this problem for now.

Comment: So, `newColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Items[5]");` didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If column doesn't have `DisplayMemberBinding` or `CellTemplate` then ToString is called on each item in the grid and evaluated value is used as cell content.

For example, if you have class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return LastName;
    }
}
```

If you bind a collection of `Person` to the grid view:

```
var people =
    new List<Person>
    {
        new Person { FirstName = "Peter", LastName = "Smith" }, 
        new Person { FirstName = "Steve", LastName = "White" },
        new Person { FirstName = "Dave", LastName = "Gates" },
    };

listView1.ItemsSource = people;
```

And if you create a new column without binding, then LastName will be shown in this column, because overridden `ToString()` returns `LastName`. If you change `ToString` to return `FirstName` then new column will show `FirstName`.

Hope I understood your question correctly.

**[Edit]**

If you add many new columns and don't use `DisplayMemberBinding` then all the new columns will evaluate and show `ToString()` result.
You need to set `DisplayMemberBinding` to show particular property.

```
var newColumn = new GridViewColumn();
newColumn.Header = "Test";
newColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("FirstName");
gridView.Columns.Add(newColumn);
```

**[Edit]**
Answers to your questions:

> When ToString() is called on every
>   item (which represents a row), how is
>   that mapped towards the columns of the
>   GridView? How must I alter an item in
>   the row so that the new column is
>   filled?

ToString is called when cell presenter is rendered, unless you specified binding or template, which would also use binding in the end. You cannot alter row item to control how it is represented in the grid, unless you override ToString or properties that are bound to the columns.

Not sure I understand your problem completely. You are adding a new column, right? Why don't you set DisplayMemberBinding property on your column? If you do this you will be able to show in the column whatever you want.

**[Edit]**

I think I answered your bounty question :). I think I already earned the bounty :).

However, here is the answer to your next question:

> > How would I set DataMemberBinding to achieve mapping to ListRow.Items[5]?

The answer:

```
newColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Items[5]");
```

Comment: So there must be a `DisplayMemberBinding` or a `CellTemplate` on the `GridViewColumn`-object? Otherwise `.ToString()` is called on the item (leading multiple new columns to all show the same content)? I'll try that out.

Comment: Are you sure that this are the only possiblities? In my case on the existing columns both, `DisplayMemberBinding` and `CellTemplate` are `null` but the columns got different contents.

Comment: What about CellStyleSelector? Also, does the grid have Style applied?

Comment: `CellStyleSelector` is also `null`. The ListView has a style, the GridView (list.View) has not. The Style at the ListView has 0 triggers but 10 setters (not matching the column count). Hope this helps. Do you need additional information?

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem completely. You are adding a new column, right? Why don't you set DisplayMemberBinding property on your column? If you do this you will be able to show in the column whatever you want.

Comment: Added a new edit in the question to clarify. Maybe I can just set `DisplayMemberBinding` although it does not seem to be set on the other columns. How would I do it so that it binds to `ListRow.Items[5]` instead of `ListRow.ToString()` (as happening now)?

Answer (score 3):

That's because the ToString() method of each items in the list is being called. If not overridden by the inheriting type, Object.ToString() returns the object's type name.

There's another issue where your list won't raise change events so the UI doesn't know the data has changed and needs to refresh.

Comment: So ItemObject.ToString() is called for every column of the grid view and for the "old" columns this return values? How is the column number passed?